# Should feature branches always branch from develop?

Tags: git, github, ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails developer and I've always had this doubt, let's say I have to develop things for the user's controller and views (branch `feature/users-endpoint`) and imagine I end up developing several helpers (sorters, paginators, etc.) and concerns to modulate the code a bit. Then let's say I have to do the admin's controller and views (branch `feature/admins-endpoint`) and I want to use the helpers and concerns I developed in `feature/users-endpoint`, **should I branch from `feature/users-endpoint` or `develop`?**

**If I branch from `develop`**:

1. Could get more merge conflicts when merging to develop (not in the exposed example, but in other cases in were I edit the same files it could).
2. Would produce a smaller Pull Request in the case of `feature/users-endpoint`.

**If I branch from `feature/users-endpoint`**:

1. Less or zero merge conflicts.
2. Would produce a much larger Pull Request in the case of `feature/users-endpoint`.

Comment: The will depend on how you deliver, and how large and slow your team is. If its just you, do what works - just be mindful of what you must deliver in order for dependent features to work. Perhaps consider Feature Toggles? If you are in a larger/slower team you will need some standards. Either try and get reviews working faster (so the feature is in `develop` before you start your next) or if that won't work you may need to pull out that functional subset into a common branch to share with the next feature.

Answer (score 1):

First - a philosophical question. You started developing on the `feature/users-endpoint` branch. However, when doing so, you introduced highly modular code. Maybe in your head you realized that this would be necessary, but it may have taken you longer to develop. Would a better option have been to not DRY up the code before it was repeated to begin with? Would you have been able to get `feature/users-endpoint` progressed through the workflow sooner - a pull request open for review, merged into a `develop` branch for other developers to use, or even deployed to a test or production environment for users or user proxies to interact with and get faster feedback?

Second - another philosophical question. What does it mean to be "done" and to "limit work in progress"? We know that limiting work in progress improves quality - it improves focus on one particular thing with less context switching which improves quality and it tends to get work through the workflow and to the next workflow faster. Should a single person have two feature branches open? What does that imply about their focus and attention?

I think that's enough of the philosophical discussion. Let's say that you're in this situation. What do you do?

Looking at the pros/cons, I believe you would almost need to branch from the `feature/users-endpoint` branch, but ensure that the `features/users-endpoint` branch is merged into the `develop` branch first. This reduces merge conflicts (reducing your workload), reduces the bulk of the pull request (reducing the mental load on code reviewers, making them more effective), and even lets you get some feedback on your `feature/users-endpoint` design, putting you in a position to find defects or perform refactoring (perhaps even before the `feature/users-endpoint` branch is merged).

Although, I do think the best thing is to not have two open feature branches. And if you must, try to make them not dependent on each other at all and have both branched from `develop`.

Answer (score 0):

You never have merge conflicts merging into develop branch. Why? Because if there are merge conflicts, you don't merge. You merge develop into your branch first, then you merge without any conflicts.

If you branch from another branch X (branched from develop) you can of course merge back into branch X. Merging into develop may be more difficult.

What I do *sometimes* if I have a branch X in review, and another feature Y requires what I did in X, then I branch from X - knowing they are both *my* branches. I can only merge Y after X has been merged. I can do that because the reviewer knows to review in the order of pull requests, so it works. I would most definitely not branch from my own branch that I'm still working on, or from someone else's branch.